# How do I encode Devanagari Back to English Encoding

Tags: java, internationalization

I am using 'Google Input Tools' for Devanagari Input in a Java application.
Following is the scenario where I am typing `Devanagari नमस्ते` in one textField, I want to show it's English equivalent `namaste` in second textBox. How to do that?

[image]

```
  private void jTextField1KeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    String input = jTextField1.getText();
    jTextField2.setText(input); // I need code here to show input in English Encoding.
    System.out.println("Input "+input);
}
```

Output:

```
  Input n
  Input na
  Input nam
  Input nama
  Input namas
  Input namast
  Input namaste
  Input नमस्ते
```

Comment: Well, I guess you need a translator or let's say converter from Devangari letters to latin ones. Try to find a Java library for that or write your own according to, for example, [Devanagari transliteration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration)

Comment: No, it does not require translator. I am  actually typing English word and it gives me devnagari equivalent.  I want to get the original English text..  Thanks for down vote, no one will care to answer now.

Comment: You are probably typing English and get Devangari because your keyboard layout in the operating system is set to do so. It has nothing to do with programming in Java.

Comment: That I already know..  But how can I read it back in English alphabets? There must be a way,  because its essential a representation of English alphabets in devnagari

Comment: I belive [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) contains [Transliterator](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4j/com/ibm/icu/text/Transliterator.html) class that can handle what you are looking for. According to [this document](http://userguide.icu-project.org/transforms/general) Devanagari should be supported.

Comment: You are talking about the English writing system, not an "English word." Just as नमस्ते is not a Devanagari word, it's a Marathi, Hindi, and maybe other languages' word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks  [Pawel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247221/pawe%C5%82-dyda) for that comment .
I looked into that library and here's the Helper class which solved my problem!

```
import com.ibm.icu.text.Transliterator;

/**
 * @author Tejas
 */

public class MarathiHelper {

    public String devanagariToLatin(String marathiString) {

        final String MAR_TO_ENG = "Devanagari-Latin";
        //final String DEV_TO_LATIN_NO_ACCENTS = "Devanagari-Latin; nfd; [:nonspacing mark:] remove; nfc";

        Transliterator toEnglish = Transliterator.getInstance(MAR_TO_ENG);
        String english = toEnglish.transliterate(marathiString);

        return english;

    }

    public String latinToDevanagari(String latinString) {

        final String ENG_TO_DEV = "Latin-Devanagari";

        Transliterator toMarathi = Transliterator.getInstance(ENG_TO_DEV);
        String marathi = toMarathi.transliterate(latinString);

        return marathi;
    }

    public String latinToAscii(String latinString){


        final String ENG_TO_DEV = "Latin-ASCII";
        Transliterator toMarathi = Transliterator.getInstance(ENG_TO_DEV);
        String ascii = toMarathi.transliterate(latinString);

        return ascii;

    }

    public String asciiToLatin(String asciiString){

        final String ENG_TO_DEV = "ASCII-Latin";
        Transliterator toMarathi = Transliterator.getInstance(ENG_TO_DEV);
        String latin = toMarathi.transliterate(asciiString);

        return latin;
    }
}
```